# Doubts about the ClassReader and the accept method

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I would like to know how the "optimization" described in the ASM user manual works.

I took a small snippet from the manual:

> If a ClassReader component detects that a MethodVisitor returned by
> the ClassVisitor passed as argument to its accept method comes from
> a ClassWriter, this means that the content of this method will not be
> transformed, and will in fact not even be seen by the application.
> In this case the ClassReader component does not parse the content of
> this method, does not generate the corresponding events, and just copies the byte array representation of this method in the ClassWriter.

More precisely, I would like to know:

1. What events does the `ClassReader` not generate when the `MethodVisitor` is retrieving from a `ClassWriter` and this is detected by the accept method?
2. Theoretically the `ClassReader` is just an event producer. Can the accept method really "copy" the content of a method to the `ClassWriter` of a `ClassVisitor` that was passed as a parameter or make any other type of modification?
3. Is the `MethodVisitor` returned by the `visitMethod` method really useful for anything? If yes, for what? I have this doubt because even returning `null` in this method, my modifications occur normally without any kind of error.

Comment: 1. The document you quoted says 'the corresponding events', which presumably means all the events handled by a `MethodVisitor`. 2. The document you quoted says that this is what happens, so clearly it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What events does the `ClassReader` not generate when the `MethodVisitor` is retrieving from a `ClassWriter` and this is detected by the accept method?

We are talking about all visit… methods of the [`MethodVisitor`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) which the class reader normally invokes.

> 2. Theoretically the `ClassReader` is just an event producer. Can the accept method really "copy" the content of a method to the `ClassWriter` of a `ClassVisitor` that was passed as a parameter or make any other type of modification?

To enable this optimization, the constant pool of the target class must be compatible with the source class. To ensure this, you have to pass the `ClassReader` to [the `ClassWriter`’s constructor](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader,int)). This is what you should do if you know that the resulting class will have enough in common to make this worthwhile. In contrast, when you have a lot of significant changes, this could leave a lot of unused artifacts in the resulting class file.

The optimization for a method applies if you pass the `MethodVisitor` from the `ClassWriter` directly to the reader, so you will not make any modification to this particular method. This is useful for all scenarios, where you only modify some of the methods or don’t modify any method and, e.g. only add new methods.

> 3. Is the `MethodVisitor` returned by the `visitMethod` method really useful for anything? If yes, for what? I have this doubt because even returning `null` in this method, my modifications occur normally without any kind of error.

How do you apply your modifications? The only way to produce executable code or methods with attributes, is by using the `MethodVisitor` returned by the `ClassWriter`’s `visitMethod`, directly or indirectly. When you don’t return any `MethodVisitor` but `null` to the reader, it will not invoke any methods on it, hence, not reproduce any of the original artifacts. This might be useful if you remove or replace the entire method, but not if you want to keep the attributes and the code, to only inject some new attributes or code. And, as the entire discussion is all about, when you pass the writer’s `MethodVisitor` directly to the reader, you will reproduce the original method in the resulting class file, whether this is done optimized or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the ClassReader, the ClassWriter can detect that a MethodVisitor is directly issued from the corresponding ClassReader. In this case, ASM does not deserialize and serialize a method but simply copied the entire methods representation from the class file.

Once you wrap a visitor, it goes back to deserializing and serializing.